# How to specify scaling down by 100 in custom numeric format string?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, number-formatting

How to specify scaling down by 100 in custom numeric format string?

I need to scale down a number by 100 (something like what the ',' operator does, scales it down by 1000)

How do i accomplish this ?

I need to divide the number by 100 and not just the comma's..

If i have a number 123456.78 i need my output as 1234.5678...

Comment: are you wanting to take a number of 1,000 and make it 1000

Comment: Do you mean that you want to group decimal digits in sets of 2?

Comment: please provide a sample output to help explain what you require.

Comment: "," does not scale the number.  It adds a thousands separator.  For example, `1234567.89d` becomes `"1,234,567.89"` with US settings, and `"1.234.567,89"` with German settings.  The numerical value is not changed.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to divide the number by 100, which has little to do with formatting. Perhaps the question could be made clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839040/custom-format-for-decimal-c-sharp/8839308#8839308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple method

```
   public static string FormatNumberSpecialNumber(double inputString)
   {
       string tempString;
       tempString = string.Format("{0:#.#####}",(inputString / 100));
       return tempString;
   }
```

usage

```
var number = FormatNumberSpecialNumber(123456.78);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in the wrong place. You should do it before you convert to string....

If you don't format with thousand seperators, you could cheat, and simply find the decimal point in the string and move it two chars to the right (given it is n't 0.2345 !)

Fragile, counter intuitive and bound to make you look like a complete wally in the future though. I'd rip you a new one in peer review, unless you were armoured with a cast iron excuse.

Answer (score 0):

First `,` is not a C# [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx), that is the wrong term. In this context it is simply a seperator.

Here is the code I would use to achieve the effect specified in your example.

```
var number = 123456.78
var formattedString = (number / 100.0).ToString();
```

EDIT:

It may be possible to do this with a custom format string (and without division) but you would need to create a custom culture that had no decimal point. I'm pretty sure there is no such culture built in.